# Grabbing list of paths contained in a file and passing them to Perl as an argument

Tags: bash, unix

Hi everyone i need a single line  command and scenario is like as below.

a file named path.txt has a path  "C:/Windows/system32/main.txt"
and that main.txt has some unicode characters.

i need to remove the unicode characters from main.txt and used below command and it worked.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' main.txt
```

so above command removed all unicode (non ascii) characters from the file.

But i need a command where the data in path.txt keeps changing it points to different file for different intervals.

i tried the below command in order to achieve it but it failed.

```
cat path.txt | perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' &1
```

could some one help me in completing the test by modifying the above script or providing with new command.

i want to achieve this only by command and not using scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `path.txt` has the list of files that you want to modify.  You can use a `read` loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r file; do
  perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' "$file"
done < path.txt
```

If you using Bash, you can run the above loop from command line, without the need to store the code in a script.

You can also achieve the same results with a Bash array as well (needs Bash 4 and above):

```
readarray -t files < paths.txt  # store all the paths from paths.txt in files array
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' "${files[@]}" # pass the array content to perl
```

You can do this in one line with

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' "$(< paths.txt)"
```

but that is strongly discouraged because of the word splitting and globbing issues.

Comment: `files=($(< paths.txt))` is bad-practice: it string-splits and glob-expands the file's contents; one can't represent filenames with spaces that way, or trust `*** MY IMPORTANT FILE NAME ***.txt` not to have been munged into a whole bunch of separate entries. Better to use `readarray -t files <paths.txt` on bash 4, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files <paths.txt || [[ ${#files[@]} ]]` if one needs compatibility with bash 3.

Comment: ...using `xargs -d $'\n'` is another option worth considering.

Comment: `files=($(< path.txt))` does seem to be safe.  I threw in the wildcard `*` into `files` as a line and the array got initialized properly.  I mean, `*` didn't get expanded.  Also, passing the array argument to Perl was safe as well.  Got `Can't open *: No such file or directory, <> line 3.` error, as expected.  However, it does do word splitting.  Changed my answer to use `readarray`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your claim above (re: "does seem to be safe"). `printf '%s\n' 'hello.txt' '*' 'bye.txt' >file; files=( $(<file) ); declare -p files` on my system shows the glob expanded.

Comment: Hmm, shows `declare -a files='([0]="hello.txt" [1]="*" [2]="bye.txt")'` for me.

Comment: Any chance `$-` includes `f`? (And which exact shell version are you testing on?)

Comment: Yes.  It is `fhimBH`.

Comment: ...so you've got globbing disabled. :)

Comment: BTW, should clear `IFS` on the first example to correctly handle filenames ending in whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ codeforester 
 "readarray -t files < paths.txt  # store all the paths from paths.txt in files array
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' "${files[@]}" # pass the array content to perl"

Isit possible to achive the above in one line.

I mean instead of writting command one time i need to do this task by using a one liner command

Comment: You can put them on a single line with a `;` in between.

Comment: I updated the answer which does give you a one command solution, which isn't recommended though.

Comment: Hi if i try to execute that command 

readarray -t files < paths.txt

it throws below error;

ksh: readarray:  not found. @codeforester

Comment: `ksh` is not `bash`; the `readarray` command is Bash only. But then why did you tag your question [tag:bash]??

Comment: oh my god can some one help me so that that  can be implemented in ksh